# Error when Ec2 running as a role tries to get a Session Token in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ec2

I'm running a app on an EC2 using a role with the the permissions:

```
"sts:GetSessionToken",
"sts:AssumeRole"
```

When I try to obtain temporary credentials using that role, I get the error:

```
Cannot call GetSessionToken with session credentials (Service: AWSSecurityTokenService; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied;
```

Am I missing one or more permissions for the role to be able to obtain temporary session credentials?

Comment: Start with `"sts:*"` and see it works. If it doesn't your role's policy is not defined correctly. If it does, make the policy granular step by step.

Comment: I added both allow "sts:*" and "iam:*" to the role but without success.

Comment: So your policy is not defined correctly. There are many examples, use them or post your policy.

Comment: @helloV You don't need a policy to call GetSessionToken. The answer Todd pointed out is actually correct. You can only call GetSessionToken using an IAM user, not a role. Credentials obtained assuming a role are session credentials already, there is no point in getting them again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to AWS support, roles cannot request temporary credentials.  Only actual Users can do that.

A work around is to use the role's credentials.  They get rolled over every hour, so they are temporary (albeit hard coded to 1 hour TTL)

Comment: When you're running with a role, your credentials *are* session credentials, (which the EC2 service obtains on behalf of your instance) hence the wording of the error, `Cannot call GetSessionToken with session credentials`.

Comment: This is very valuable. Are there any aws docs on this @Michael-sqlbot

Comment: @Mathemats I'm not 100% sure which part you're asking about, but [the EC2 infrastructure uses `sts:AssumeRole` to automatically obtain instance role credentials for your instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html) and the resulting [*"temporary security credentials created by `AssumeRole` can be used to make API calls to any AWS service with the following exception: You cannot call the AWS STS `GetFederationToken` or `GetSessionToken` API operations."*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html)

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot The problem I faced was I was trying to use the EC2 instance role to generate session tokens - which you can't. Instead I made a new IAM user and gave it the policies I needed.

Comment: @Mathemats a lot of people incorrectly use GetSessionToken when really they should be using AssumeRole.  GetSessionToken has almost no valid use cases except maybe MFA, while AssumeRole can be called from another role and is the correct way to get temporary credentials in most cases.