# What is the AWS CLI equivalent of boto3's Session.get_credentials() function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, boto3, aws-cli

I am working in an EC2 instance that can has connectivity to an S3 bucket and to a Redshift instance.  From the EC2 instances's command line, I can do `aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket/my-folder/` and it magically works.  However, from within Redshift, when I want to import data with the `copy` command, I need to supply credentials.

The credentials that that the `aws` CLI are using do not exist within my `~/.aws/credentials` file.  I have found I can infer my (temporary, apparently) credentials using the boto3 Python library as follows:

```
session = boto3.Session()
creds = session.get_credentials()
creds = creds.get_frozen_credentials()

credentials = {
    'aws_access_key_id': creds.access_key,
    'aws_secret_access_key': creds.secret_key,
    'token': creds.token,
}

credStr = ';'.join(k+'='+v for k,v in sorted(credentials.items()))
```

This gives me a credentials string that looks like this:

`aws_access_key=XXX;aws_secret_access_key=YYY;token=ZZZ`

I can then use that credentials string to write `copy` statements in Redshift as follows:

```
copy
  my_table
from
  's3://my-bucket/my.manifest'
credentials 'aws_access_key=XXX;aws_secret_access_key=YYY;token=ZZZ'
manifest
```

I have written a helper script that I can call from the command line to spit out my credentials, but it would be cleaner if I could get the above information from the `aws` cli tool, rather than having to call up a homegrown Python script.

***SO: How do I do the equivalent of `boto3.Session().get_credentials().get_frozen_credentials()` using the `aws` CLI?***

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT:** Please note: Running `aws sts get-caller-identity` implies I am running as a role, and not a user.  Therefore, calling `aws sts get-session-token` will not work, since [roles cannot request temporary credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35873012/error-when-ec2-running-as-a-role-tries-to-get-a-session-token-in-aws).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone finding this via Google, [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html) led me to this solution:

```
role=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials)

# The below also works to get the role, but it is slower and has more dependencies.
#role=$(aws sts get-caller-identity | jq -r ".Arn" | sed -r 's@.*assumed-role/(.*)/.*@\1@')

api_token=$(curl -X PUT "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token" -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 21600")

read -r key secret token <<<$(curl -H "X-aws-ecw-metadata-token: $api_token" -v http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/$role | jq -r '.AccessKeyId,.SecretAccessKey,.Token')

creds="aws_access_key_id=$key;aws_secret_access_key=$secret;token=$token"
```

I would still be interested to know whether there is a way to do this as a one-step process in the `aws` CLI, if anyone knows...

**EDIT:** Incorporated Michael's helpful suggestion below.

**EDIT:** Fixed typo in `aws_access_key`.

Comment: No, I don't think so, but you should be able to get the role name much faster by hitting the metadata endpoint `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/info` and it will be exponentially faster than your call to `sts get-caller-identity`.

Comment: Thanks!  It looks like the role in iam/info has a role name with more dashes on it after the "normal" part I want, but I can also just get the role from iam/security-credentials, and just using curl as you describe is much cleaner.  Thanks for your help.  I've incorporated that change into the answer.

Answer (score 2):

try `aws sts get-session-token`

Your output should look something like this:

```
{
    "Credentials": {
        "AccessKeyId": "XXXXXXXXX",
        "SecretAccessKey": "XXXXXXXX",
        "SessionToken": "XXXXXXX",
        "Expiration": "2020-03-18T08:15:08Z"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  However, I believe I need to infer the values of *existing* credentials, whereas I believe get-session-token generates *new* credentials.  When I run aws sts get-session-token, I get: "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetSessionToken operation: Cannot call GetSessionToken with session credentials".

Comment: These are temporary credentials based on your long term credentials. They only exist till the time in ‘expiration’. They are not permanent which fits your use case perfectly. For the error, it looks like you don’t have permissions to call ‘get-session-token’. Check the IAM policy of your cli user.

Comment: Please see this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35873012/error-when-ec2-running-as-a-role-tries-to-get-a-session-token-in-aws

"[R]oles cannot request temporary credentials.  Only actual users can do that."

I am apparently logged in as a role (which by the way is implied by the arn that `aws sts get-caller-identity` returns).  Therefore, I need a way to get my role's credentials.  Requesting new credentials using `aws sts get-session-token` is a non-starter, since I am apparently acting as a role, not a user.